# Calculate the grand total with javascript (onkeyup)

Tags: javascript

How calculate grand total from total using java script (onkeyup)?
This my coding

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <form method = "POST" action="text.php" name="form">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function cal1() {
        var a = $(".qty1").val();
        var b = $(".price1").val();
        c1 = a * b; //a * b
        $(".total1").val(c1);
        }

        function cal2() {
        var a = $(".qty2").val();
        var b = $(".price2").val();
        c2 = a * b; //a * b
        $(".total2").val(c2);
        }

        function grandtotal() {
        var a = $(".total1").val();
        var b = $(".total2").val();
        z = a+b; //+
        $(".grandtotal").val(z);
        }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>


<table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table height="51" border="0" cellspacing="2">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div align="center">Price</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div align="center"> Total Price</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>

                                    <td>
                                        <input  class="qty1"  type="text" name="qty1" onblur="qty_blur(this);" onkeyup="cal1();" value="">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input  class="price1"  type="text" name="price1" onblur="price_blur(this);" onkeyup="cal1();" value="">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input  class="total1"  type="text" name="total1" value="0" readonly=true onkeyup="grandtotal();">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input  class="qty2"  type="text" name="qty2" onblur="qty_blur(this);" onkeyup="cal2();" value="">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input  class="price2"  type="text" name="price2" onblur="price_blur(this);" onkeyup="cal2();" value="">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input  class="total2"  type="text" name="total2" value="0" readonly=true onkeyup="grandtotal();">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr div class="grandtotal">
                        <td>
                            Grand Total :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="grandtotal" name="grandtotal" type="text" readonly=true value="">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </div>
                </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

it's already correct for cal1 and cal2, but grand total keep empty when cal and cal2 already calculate?? how to grand total auto calculate +??? form total cal1 and total cal2

Comment: Use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to parse the text values from the input fields to a numeric value. (So: `var a = parseInt($(".total1").val());`)

Comment: and may I suggest you also use `var` before `c1`, `c2` and `z`? (otherwise they will be cast as global variables)

Comment: Thx for ur comment, u mind like this? var a = parseInt($(".qty1").val());
   var b = parseInt($(".price1").val());
   var c1 = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
   $(".total1").val(c1);

Comment: A form in the `<head>` section? Pretty strange.

Comment: yes, except when calculating `var c1` you don't need to `parseInt` anymore because the values `a` and `b` are already parsed

Comment: **But make sure you know the difference between `parseInt` and `parseFloat`, especially for the price I can imagine you need `parseFloat`**

Comment: @myfunkyside Thx for u comment really help :D, float for decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have associated the `grandtotal` to the `onkeyup` totals inputs. But those inputs will never receive an `onkeyup` because they are `readonly`.

As a quick solution I suggest simply calling `grandtotal` from `cal1` and `cal2`:

```
    function cal1() {
      var a = $(".qty1").val();
      var b = $(".price1").val();
      c1 = a * b; //a * b
      $(".total1").val(c1);
      grandtotal();
    }

    function cal2() {
      var a = $(".qty2").val();
      var b = $(".price2").val();
      c2 = a * b; //a * b
      $(".total2").val(c2);
      grandtotal();
    }
```

Also, as @myfunkyside suggest, you have to properly parse the inputs to numbers. Otherwise you'll get the totals concatenated as strings.

```
    function grandtotal() {
      var a = parseInt($(".total1").val(), 10);
      var b = parseInt($(".total2").val(), 10);
      z = a+b; //+
      $(".grandtotal").val(z);
    }
```